# Javascript promise and function : getting error

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I can't understand why Firefox said : "TypeError: fadeIn_1(...) is undefined"
and Chrome said "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" with this code :

```js
function fadeIn_1(cpt) {
  cpt = cpt + step;
  if (cpt < 500) {
    console.log("cpt = " + cpt);
    setTimeout(function() {
      fadeIn_1(cpt);
    }, ticks);
  } else {
    console.log("cpt = " + cpt);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve("Succeed");
      console.log("THE END. Ticks = " + ticks);
    });
  }
}

var cpt = 1;
var step = 10;
var TimeDuration = 500; // ms
var ticks = 15; // Duration.

fadeIn_1(cpt).then(function() {
  console.log('Promise executed !');
});
```

The result I want : "Promise executed" in the console.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: you aren't returning a promise when `cpt < 500`.

Comment: That's true, but the initial value is `500` and it adds to it each time. I can't reproduce the error with those values.

Comment: I take that back. The error shows up in the real console, but not the Stack Snippet console emulator.

Comment: I don't know where I got the idea that the initial value is 500. It's not using `TimeDuration` for that. The problem is as @DanielA.White said. Since you start with `cpt = 1`, it takes the first `if` branch and doesn't return a promise.

Comment: You're right, TimeDuration is not needed. But when cpt > 500, console.log shows "THE END. Ticks = " + ticks; but there is no resolve()...

Comment: right. that is expected. The original function never returned a promise. .then was never called *on* a promise, and therefore the callback you passed for it doesn't exist.

Comment: @KevinB I understand there is no return of promise. But why       console.log("THE END. Ticks = " + ticks) is executed and resolve("Succeed") is NOT executed ?

Comment: Because both of them ARE executed. but nothing is listening for that promise to resolve so it falls on deaf ears.

Comment: @KevinB I think I have to find another tuto because something missed me to understand your answers  ;-)

Comment: The first time you call the function, it doesn't return anything. There's nothing to call .then on, which is why an error occurs.

Comment: @KevinB OK I understand now, thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

You should always make sure your functions have consistent returns. In this case, your function either returns a promise, or undefined. Lets make it always return a promise by promisifying setTimeout.

```js
function promisifiedSetTimeout(delay) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, delay);
  });
}
function fadeIn_1(cpt) {
  cpt = cpt + step;
  if (cpt < 500) {
    console.log("cpt = " + cpt);
    return promisifiedSetTimeout(ticks).then(function() {
      return fadeIn_1(cpt);
    });
  } else {
    console.log("cpt = " + cpt);
    console.log("THE END. Ticks = " + ticks);
    return Promise.resolve("Succeed");
  }
}

var cpt = 1;
var step = 10;
var TimeDuration = 500; // ms
var ticks = 15; // Duration.

fadeIn_1(cpt).then(function() {
  console.log('Promise executed !');
});
```

Because we returned the next call to `fadeIn_1` to the `.then` of the timeout, it further delays the original `.then` until they are all complete.

Comment: It works !  Thank you very much for all your answers.